# Windows 10 start-menu/taskbar/desktop issue

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, start-menu

I'm not sure if this was caused by a random string of keystrokes I entered or what, but my start menu and taskbar now look kind of strange:

[image: Screenshot]

I had pretty much the default before. As you can see, all my icons have disappeared and I now have a "back" button. Clicking the windows icon does nothing, and on top of that, I can't minimize or resize any windows I have open.

I've tried restarting my computer to no avail! So what's gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out my laptop decided to switch to tablet mode (control panel -> settings -> tablet mode). Turning it off fixed my issue!